# Webstorm How do I set the context root for my application?

Tags: webstorm

I'm having a heck of a time figuring this out (and I assume it is a basic problem and I'm just searching for the wrong terms). I have a plain html site that I'm trying to debug locally and when I open it in a browser or debug it I get this url:

`http://localhost:63342/DeleteMe/root/index.html`

If I set my resource root to the `root` folder I end up with:

`http://localhost:63342/DeleteMe/index.html`

The problem is I use "absolutely" pathed resources such as `/js/utility.js` because the context shifts based on what AJAX content is pulled in (Hijax-ish application).

What I'd like to see is->

`http://localhost:63342/index.html`

`http://localhost:63342/js/utility.js`

for a project like:

```
[DeleteMe] <--project root
  - root
    - js
      utility.js
    - index.html
```

I'm interested in a solution that deals directly with this problem **inside the IDE**. I already have a host of tools for web development and I'm evaluating JetBrains at the moment and these little details are what make the difference for me. I can easily set up IIS or Apache to preview the site, I'm looking for a complete solution in a single IDE.

*(For reference the project was developed using Eclipse)*

Comment: 1) You are trying to use **SIMPLE** built-in web server -- it's very limited in configuration/functionality -- it just serves files as is. 2) There is no settings in WebStorm to specify **website root folder** (for "Open in Browser" actions) -- ticket is there, but who knows when it will be implemented.

Comment: 3) ATM you can only simplify URL **a bit**: instead of `http://localhost:63342/DeleteMe/root/index.html` you can make `http://DeleteMe:63342/root/index.html` (you will need to point `DeleteMe` to `127.0.0.1` via your `hosts` file or local DNS server. For "Open in Browser" actions to work with such URL by default you will need to setup Deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project.

Comment: @LazyOne --thanks for the information. I'll give the latter (host files) a shot. This is really unfortunate as any JavaScript application bringing in content is going to require a real web server and not a "file path" (security exceptions). Feel free to post this as an answer--it seems like the hosts file will probably work.

Comment: hosts file can't work as a solution since the problem isn't host resolution- its the path on the host. the hosts file can't be used to match the '/DeleteMe/' path.

Comment: @stealthwang I think the question is misleading, there are two problems here. Thebfirst is the context root (annoying but you can work around it) the second is the inherent security errors when trying to use an AJAX request from a file resource. The answer to this question is: no, web storm does not provide any functionality out of the box and therefore isn't the tool you need for this. Could it be tricked into working? Probably. Is it worth it? No, not for my workflow (I abandoned it and use Visual Studio or Sublime Text/Chrome).

Comment: @LazyOne [WEB-11949 - simplify web server document root configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11949) I believe this is the ticket you are referring to. "2) There is no settings in WebStorm to specify website root folder (for "Open in Browser" actions) -- ticket is there, but who knows when it will be implemented". Please everyone who would like this functionality, go vote for the ticket :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use your deployed test version to run the application? When I started using Webstorm I had those problems. Then I figured out that Webstorm can debug your source anywhere your are running it.

So, I have my appache set, with any root I want, and I point the sources (using symlinks) to the real source in the project.

Then, I create a configuration for each of the servers I want to use, like this:

[image]

I also use that approach, together with hosts, to have multiple different debug environments (for different users, for instance). This is a stretch of my windows hosts file (in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc):

```
...
127.0.0.1 crewhu-admin
127.0.0.1 crewhu-company
127.0.0.1 crewhu-manager
127.0.0.1 crewhu-employee
...
```

And the debug process for javascript works like a charm for all environments.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm sure this is a workaround, but I've abandoned Webstorm. As I stated in my original question: `I'm interested in a solution that deals directly with this problem inside the IDE`. I'm sure this approach will help someone down the road, but this is still more complex than `configure correctly`->`start server`. (Also this thread is nearly two years old)